# Sql Server reporting services over bcp

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bcp

Currently in our organisation we aren't using reporting services in Sql Server anywhere. I have a task where i need to fetch data using a query and dump it to some local drive on daily basis. All the dump task currently are done using bcp utility. 
I want to know if this task can be done using Sql Server Reporting Services.
PS: i have read a lot about reporting services but i am not clear
1. if we can dump file on daily basis like a job does.
2. if we can add parametrised query to fetch data and pass parameters in configurable way.
please suggest if using reporting services would be beneficial in my case?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Reporting Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106(v=sql.120).aspx) is used to create and manage reports.  It does not do administrative tasks, like execute jobs or scripts.  So to answer your questions:

1. No, you cannot dump files on a daily basis, that is what SQL Server Agent does.
2. Yes, SSRS reports can accept parameters, but only to dynamically display data.  There is nothing here in the way of executing BCP.

Comment: Thanks. i will use bcp in that case.